# Spring autowiring in flyway

Tags: java, spring, flyway

How can I inject a Spring bean in class that implements `org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.JavaMigration` ?

It seems it's been added in Flyway 6.0: [This issue](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1062) seems to talk about it, but I don't really see how to proceed.

I've also seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48214783/flyway-spring-boot-autowired-beans-with-jpa-dependency/48242865#48242865) which seems to talk about it, but I was hoping there was a shorter solution (I don't have the requirement about the JPA dependency that the author speaks about).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Spring Boot:

1. First you will need to disable the initialization and triggering of flyway by setting the `spring.flyway.enabled` to `false`. This also means you will have to configure Flyway yourself.
2. Annotate your `JavaMigrations` classes with `@Component`.
3. Create a Class that implements `CommandLineRunner` and implements the run method. This class should also have your `JavaMigrations` autowired and your datasource url, user and password will also need to be injected as well or alternatively a `DataSource` object.
4. In the `run` method collect your `JavaMigrations` objects into an array and programmatically register them with Flyway and then run the migration:

   ```
   JavaMigrations migrations[] = {myJavaMigration};
   Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure()
                        .dataSource(url, user, password)
                        .javaMigrations(migrations)
                        .load();
   flyway.migrate();
   ```

Full implementation:

```
@Component
public class MyJavaMigration extends BaseJavaMigration {
...
}

@Component
public class MyFlywayMigration implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private MyJavaMigration myJavaMigration;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource; 

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
      JavaMigrations migrations[] = {myJavaMigration};
      Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure()
                            .dataSource(dataSource)
                            .javaMigrations(migrations)
                            .load();
      flyway.migrate();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to turn `spring.flyway.enabled` =`false`. The above code can be simplified to just `Flyway.configure().javaMigrations(myJavaMigration).load()` as long as you have `myJavaMigration` in your class path.