# Flyway 6 JavaMigrations with Native Dependency Injection for Spring Beans

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-data, flyway

I have seen many great workarounds to create Flyway JavaMigrations and injecting Spring Beans using `@DependsOn` and `ApplicationContextAware` (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48242865/5244937).

However a part of the Flyway 6 documentation claims Dependency Injection would be possible natively for Spring Beans:

- https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/hooks#java-based-migrations-as-spring-beans
- https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1062

Is is true? How would this work?

Comment: By this line: ApplicationContext applicationContext = ...; // obtain a reference to Spring's ApplicationContext.

Comment: Until now I have only used SQL based migrations and Flyways autodiscovery feature. Do I understand correctly that this will longer work with this approach and instead I need to ..
 - Manually kick off the migrations?
 - Use the pattern (1) Instantiate Spring Bean / FlywayMigrationInitializer, (2) Find the migrations manually using `.javaMigrations(..)` and (3) kick off flyway manually via 
 `flyway.migrate();`?

Comment: No SQL will still work and is IMHO the preferred way.

Answer (score 5):

Mark your migrations as `@Component` and put them in a folder that is **scanned** by spring (e.g. within your application package and not in `db.migrations`). This will ensure `@Autowired` can be used because the bean is instantiated by spring. (The migrations in `db.migrations` will be scanned by flyway automatically and are not instantiated by spring.)

Then implement a `FlywayConfigurationCustomizer` to add the migrations by loading them from the spring context:

```
@Configuration
class FlywayConfiguration implements FlywayConfigurationCustomizer {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void customize(FluentConfiguration configuration) {
        JavaMigration[] migrationBeans = applicationContext
         .getBeansOfType(JavaMigration.class)
         .values().toArray(new JavaMigration[0]);
        configuration.javaMigrations(migrationBeans);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer of @Stuck (lombok optional of course).

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FlywayConfiguration implements FlywayConfigurationCustomizer {
    
    final JavaMigration[] migrations;

    @Override
    public void customize(FluentConfiguration configuration) {
        configuration.javaMigrations(migrations);
    }
}
```